# Right linear grammar special case

Tags: regular-languages, formal-grammars

According to the definition, the productions of a right linear grammar should have the form of $A\to xB$ or $A\to x$,
does $A\to B$ or $A\to xy$ count as productions of a right linear grammar? $A\to B$ can be written as $A\to \epsilon B$ though...

Comment: Where have you looked?  What research have you done?  This seems to be answered on Wikipedia, in the obvious place: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar#Strictly_regular_grammars, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_grammar#Relationship_with_regular_grammars.  If your question is answered in the obvious place on Wikipedia, probably you should be doing more research before asking.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your definition, $x$ must be a terminal symbol. In particular, it cannot be $\epsilon$, which is the empty string. The productions $A \to B$ and $A \to xy$ don't conform to the specifications you give, hence they don't belong in a right linear grammar according to the definition you provide.